# Multiplicativity of the Euler characteristic in an equivariant setting

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology

Let $E$ and $B$ be two complex varieties with finite group $G$-actions. Suppose there is a $G$-equivariant morphism $f\colon E\to B$ such that $f$ is a locally trivial fiber bundle with fiber $F$ in the complex topology. Denote by $[e(X)]:=\sum_{i}(-1)^{i}[H_{c}^{i}(X,\mathbb{C})]$ the alternating sum of the compactly supported singular cohomology groups as virtual $G$-representations. Assume that $B$ is irreducible. Is there a $G$-action on the cohomology groups of $F$ such that $[e(E)]=[e(B)][e(F)]$ as virtual $G$-representations $?$ For example, when $E\to B$ is a trivial bundle, although there may not be a well-defined action of $G$ on $F$, I think there is a well-defined action of $G$ on the cohomology groups of $F$.